# Incremental JAR update for J2ME MIDlet

Tags: java-me, jar, nokia, midp, s60

I need to update an application JAR file by sending a minimal incremental update of my J2ME code and res/ folder. What is the best way of doing this. This JAR gets installed on a phone. In so doing, I want to minimize the size of the update I send to the phone. I am developing with Eclipse for Nokia N97 SDK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't update individual classes or resources on the fly.  You could download new resources, and save them either to RMS or the file system using JSR75.

Beyond that, you'll need to install a new JAR.

Comment: I had something like a "diff" in mind to update a JAR. So apart from sending the resources folder, some sort of a diff to the JAR (something like a patch).

Comment: Yes I understand that that's what you had in mind, but it's not possible.